# Can someone explain the geographical name "Switch"?

Tags: toponyms, geography

It generally used as a town name such as "Lyons Switch, OK" or "Bridges Switch, CO". I've seen it used many times over the years and never gave it much thought but recently became curious as to the specific definition of this term. I thought it might have come from towns along a railway for instance but some of these locales are nowhere near a railroad. If anyone has info on this thanks in advance!

Comment: The Colorado one is just a place inside Clifton (by Grand Junction), [right next to a train track](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bridges+Switch,+CO+81520/@39.0988432,-108.4041826,189m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x874721c0a7bf184f:0x91ad4f387102948a!8m2!3d39.0985923!4d-108.4039767). I don't know that it's an actual town, *per se*.

Comment: I don't think we have any such names in the UK, but based on the two examples and the previous comment, I believe a "railway switch" in AmE is what we, in BrE, would call a points. The device for changing (or switching) a train track to send the train down one of two different paths. Hence I would guess that "Something Switch" is a place where a railway line splits int two different routes. Possibly marking an important junction in the network.

Comment: A quick search of an online UK gazetteer turned up a slack handful of "settlements" with names including the word *Junction*.  The first, *Battersby Junction*, stands on a place where two (now defunct if I read the map correctly) railway lines meet.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I confess I didn't go looking on the map, but I'm pretty sure that you are right and "Something Junction" is the UK equivalent of "Somewhere Switch" in the US. It's worth noting that Clapham Junction is probably the most famous of those places in the UK. It's a major coming together of railway lines in SW London. LInes from all over the South ans SW of England converge on it before they are routed to several main terminus stations in the capital.

Comment: Please, I plead,  mods, do not delete the comments! They're not answers but interesting insights and suppositions.

Comment: Which locales are (or were) nowhere near a railroad?

Comment: "nowhere near a railroad": A lot of railroad lines have disappeared. There were railroads in the past in many places where there are no railroads now.

Answer (score 9):

A railroad switch ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_switch)) is a feature in a railroad where the track branches off and trains can be sent in two separate directions. In the UK they are known as points, and the place where the track branches is called a junction. Many settlements at or near railroad switches have the placename element Switch.

A number of places in the United States are located at railroad switches and named after them. This includes [Gravel Switch, Kentucky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravel_Switch,_Kentucky), [Grinder's Switch, Tennessee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinder%27s_Switch,_Tennessee), and  [Barnes Switch, Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_Switch,_Texas). Wikipedia says they were named after switches but doesn't offer any evidence; however it may be too obvious to need proof. Gravel Switch was located at a branch to a gravel quarry on the  Louisville and Nashville Railroad Lebanon Branch, while  Grinder's Switch had a railway depot and a switch to access it. Barnes Switch lies at a switch on the the Waco, Beaumont, Trinity and Sabine Railway.

Lyon's Switch, Oklahoma is located near a railway line which passed through nearby [Stilwell, OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stilwell,_Oklahoma) although it's not clear if there was a junction or railroad yard there.

Bridges Switch, Colorado appears the exception; it is near Grand Junction, but that is a river junction.

Comment: It is (obviously) worth remembering that railroads were much more important when these places were founded; often the towns were created *because* of the railroads or their intersections, rather than the railroads being built to connect preexisting towns.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that in UK rail-industry terminology, 'switches and crossings', often abbreviated to 'S & C' are what Joe Public calls 'points'. In particular, Joe P is usually thinking of the simple type of S & C which allows a train to optionally turn aside to another line, called a 'turnout'.

Comment: This is probably the right explanation, but there is still something puzzling about giving such a name to a town on the basis of one railroad line branching off from another there. It leaves the impression that only one switch is involved, while a station located at such a junction is likely to have quite a few switches, none of which may be obviously **the** switch. For that matter there are normally quite a few switches around every railroad station, including those where no line branches off from another.

Comment: "According to Palisade resident Basil T. Knight, the Bridges' Switch Store was located in Palisade, Colorado, on 35 Road north of the railroad tracks, in the early Twentieth century." —https://opac.marmot.org/Archive/place:2840/Place (Palisade is 3 miles from Bridges Switch.)

Comment: @jsw29 - My local railway/road station has no switches anywhere near it. Any station located on plain line with no junction nearby will be like that. A station on a double line where another double line branches off will usually have exactly two switches, and if the lines are single, then there would be only one.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean S & C is a technical term that does get used but it's wrong to think 'points' is somehow what members of the public call them, whereas on the railway they're called switches and crossings. The Rule Book has 475 instances of the word 'points' (far too many for me to be sure that none of them refer to other kinds of points, e.g. 'access point') whereas I think that the only instances of 'switch' that refer to S & C are in the phrase '**points**, switch diamonds and swing-nose crossings'. See also, 'facing point lock', 'points indicator', etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Etymology switch"](https://youtu.be/naoknj1ebqI?t=40)

> switch (n.)
>
> 1590s, "slender riding whip," probably from a Flemish or Low German
> word akin to Middle Dutch swijch "bough, twig," or swutsche, variant
> of Low German zwukse "long thin stick, switch," from Germanic *swih-
> (source also of Old High German zwec "wooden peg," German Zweck "aim,
> design," originally "peg as a target," Zwick "wooden peg"), perhaps
> connected with PIE root *swei- (2) "to swing, bend, to turn."
>
> The meaning "device for changing the direction of something or making
> or breaking a connection" is first recorded 1797. "The peg sense suits
> the mech(anical) applications" [Weekley]; also compare switchblade.
> These senses in English might be a direct borrowing from those senses
> in Continental Germanic languages rather than a continuation of the
> "pliant wand" sense. The meaning "a change from one to another, a
> reversal, an exchange, a substitution" is first recorded 1920;
> extended form switcheroo is by 1933.
>
> switch (v.)
>
> 1610s, "to strike with a switch," from switch (n.). Related: Switched;
> switching. The meaning "turn (off or on) with a switch device" is
> first recorded 1853 of trains on tracks, 1881 of electricity, 1932 of
> radio or (later) television. Sense of "shift, divert" is from 1860.
> Meaning "to change one thing for another" is recorded from 1919.
> Switch-hitter is 1945 in baseball slang; 1956 in the sense of
> "bisexual person."

Note that the electrical/railroad meaning dates from 1797.  The bough/twig meaning is much earlier (and was still popular with mothers when I was a kid).

Comment: And a different etymology for Ipswitch England https://xefer.com/2009/05/ipswich

Answer (score 0):

and sorry for the lengthy delay for my reply. First thanks for all the responses!
I know some names with switch are adjacent to railroads, and some are not (even historically) according to old government maps. (The United States Geological Survey has an EXCELLENT site with ALL US Topography maps: [https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/topoview/][1] . The maps date back as far as 1880.) Some place names, even if they did not exist on the earlier maps, do not show any railroad ever at the town site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).